# Where are the .net core dlls stored on my computer?

Tags: asp.net-core

I cannot find the dlls. Visual Studio does not tell you where they are stored. I want to load them into .net Reflector.

Comment: You mean the built in dlls?

Comment: C:\Program Files\dotnet if you mean system dlls

Comment: C:\Program Files\dotnet\store\x64\netcoreapp2.0

Comment: Technically, it's installed as a nuget package. The DLLs in the runtime are mostly there for the dotnet component. .NET Core applications are self-contained.

Comment: Not by default. .NET core apps still reference the framework dlls outside the bin folder.

Comment: Goodness, why is that a downvote?

Comment: I am not entirely sure why u have two downvotes but it might be because of clarity

Comment: it it is acessed from outside, can't you check it from the properties?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane It doesn't show the physical location in .net core.

Comment: You know that .NET Core is open source on GitHub, right? So you don’t actually need to decompile anything.

Comment: If you can find it, yes.

Comment: e.g. Where is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions`?

Comment: Okay, the ASP.NET Core ones are sometimes a bit difficult to find. That one is [in `aspnet/HttpAbstractions`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions/AuthenticationOptions.cs). You can use GitHub’s advanced search though, limited to the `aspnet` organization. That should help.

Comment: @poke oh great, thanks.

Comment: @poke So how did you find that file? Also, Reflector lets you navigate around the code by clicking on symbols and analysing usages.

Comment: Either [using search](https://github.com/search?l=&q=AuthenticationOptions+user%3Aaspnet&ref=advsearch&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) or, if you know which repository to look in, using GitHub’s file finder (press `T` inside a repository to open it).

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but if you're looking for these then check out the following location...

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
```

Under there should be versions of .NET Core, and these are the runtime assemblies you'll need to load in Refelctor to see the source code.

Note - if you use an assembly reference from within Visual Studio (by maybe clicking F12 on a .NET Core datatype or interface), that will show the **reference** assembly and **not** the implementation assembly.

As an example, hitting F12 on ControllerBase gives me this...

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll
```

This is **not** the runtime assembly you need when using Reflector. GitHub is all fair and good for finding source code to one method, but you can't beat Reflector when you want to move between different classes in different files so as to work through an implementation pathway.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can set them up I  properties. They are still in the bin folder once the code is compiled. Although if you are planning on using the dll directly you can publish then first